# Why textview not updating on UI thread?

Tags: android, view, ui-thread

I was trying to modify the SlidingTabLayout from github. I am trying to change the picture every time scrolling the tab. i.e. trying to make the current tab highlighted by different image. So I tried to modify the onPageSelected() method to redraw the entire tab menu. But the tab menu is not updating, I tried different approaches but nothing happens.

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        final PagerAdapter mAdapter = mPagerAdapter;
        mPagerAdapter.current = position;
        for(int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);

            //Log.d("onPageSelected","Ok");
            final TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            final CharSequence temp = mAdapter.getPageTitle(i);

            ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    tv.setText(temp);
                }
            });

        }

            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
        }
        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }

    }

}
```

So, what's wrong with this segment? My adapter's getPageTitle() returns the Charsequence of the image. What am I doing wrong ? I am new in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every loop iteration you inflate a *new* view which is never used.

You need to modify the views created by your adapter's `instantiateItem()`.